# Временно зафиксировать координаты картинки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть [плагин](http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/53fE9/) ресайза картинки. [Скрипт плагина](http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/jquery.cropbox.js). При перезагрузке страницы (F5), координаты картинки сбрасываются на дефолтные. Нужно что-то вроде такого (планирую подставлять значения из базы данных).

```
$(function() {
    $('.cropimage')
          cropX: 400,
          cropY: 272,
          cropW: 200,
          cropH: 200
});/*код не рабочий*/
```

Т.е. зафиксировать координаты, но при этом, можно было бы продолжать работать с плагином.

Comment: Храните координаты где-нить. Варианты

 * server
 * local storage
 * cookie

Comment: Вопрос ни где хранить, а как зафиксировать картину при перезагрузке страницы?

Comment: Восстанавливайте координаты из того где храните.

Comment: Да я и буду восстанавливать из того где храню. Вопрос-то не в этом.